# What does "justement" qualify in this sentence?

Tags: sens

> On se demandait **justement** comment y aller quand on t'a trouvée.

I’m torn between two possible interpretations. Which one is correct?

> 1. We were **just** wondering how to get there when we found you.

{ “Just” is used to qualify "wondering" and means “we were **merely** wondering”. }

> 2. We were wondering **just** how to get there when we found you.

{ “Just” is used to qualify and emphasise “how”. It’s like “**exactly** how”. }

---

I’m leaning towards the second interpretation. If I’m correct here, is it ever possible – depending on context – to use "justement" for the meaning of the first interpretation?

Comment: I would translate "On se demandait précisément comment y aller quand on ta trouvée." "How to get there was precisely what we were wondering when we found you".

Comment: Dans cette phrase justement indique une coïncidence. [Voir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/justement) B2.

Comment: @Stéphane « Comment y aller... c'est justement ce qu'on se demandait quand on t'a trouvée. » So you've thrown the third interpretation into the mix! The plot thickens. :) Merci.

Comment: @Laure         I now see that "justement" can refer to a coincidental situation as well. So is it more like "**As it happens**, we were wondering how to get there when we found you."? Merci.

Comment: Personally I would not use *justement* for any of your two interpretations. #1 *ne...que*; #2 *avec précision*. Stéphane is right, in your sentence *justement* is synonym of *précisément*. "Precisely" can be used in that sense too. Addendum: "as it happens" is an excellent translation, yes, précisément. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Justement** peut avoir plusieurs sens :

**1-** En accord avec une idée de justice :

> Il a fait un excellent travail et il a été justement récompensé par un premier prix.

**2-** Avec justesse (dans le sens de rigueur) :

> Je dirais très justement que les adverbes *juste* et *justement* doivent être différenciés.

C'est synonyme de « exactement » ou « précisément » dans ce cas.

**3-** Sert à marquer la concordance de deux faits ou la simultanéité de deux actions :

> On se demandait justement comment y aller quand on t'a trouvée.

C'est synonyme de « au moment où » (→ Au moment où on t'a trouvée on se demandait comment y aller), on peut aussi employer « précisément » dans ce sens là. C'est certainement le sens le plus courant de « justement ».

4- Dans un dialogue, placé en début de phrase, il sert à « justifier » (→ dans le sens de donner une raison) :

> A- Tes parents vont s'inquiéter s'ils apprennent que tu es malade.
> B- Justement, je ne vais rien leur dire.

Par ailleurs il ne faut pas confondre les emplois de « juste » (adverbe) et de « justement ».

> Je veux juste te parler. → Je ne veux que te parler, rien d'autre.
>
> Je veux justement te parler. →  Ça tombe bien que tu sois là parce que j'ai quelque chose à te dire.

À propos des deux phrases de ta question :

> *We were just wondering how to get there when we found you*.

→ Nous nous demandions juste comment y aller quand nous t'avons trouvée.

> *We were wondering just how to get there when we found you.*

→ On se demandait comment précisément y aller quand ...

Je n'ai pas écrit :

> On se demandait comment y aller précisément quand ...
> ou
> On se demandait précisément comment y aller précisément quand ...

parce que dans ces deux dernières phrases « précisément » aurait été compris comme « justement » (3- ci-dessus).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your first interpretation is better. In your french sentence, "justement" is a matter of time like :

> We were wondering at the moment how to...

This is my interpretation ;)

Comment: You could  in a way say it is "a matter of time" in as far as  it shows two actions occuring almost simultaneously (se demander & trouver la personne) but you absolutely cannot translate justement  "at the moment" in OP's sentence. "Precisely" would be the right word here.

Comment: Or "actually" : "actually, we were wondering..." carries the same meaning.